# Full screen image with image placed in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to centre an image, i've attached a jsfiddle to show the outcome of what I want, the only difference would be that the image is placed into the html and not the css code.

http://jsfiddle.net/6y2qjxm0/3/

Here's the css I'm using in the fiddle and i've already taken the image url out.

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

and finally here's the html:

```
<div class="full-screen">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Failing this, does anyone know a better way of doing this?

It must be centred and it must be 100% width and 100% height.

Thanks

UPDATE: The image must stay in proportion like the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size: cover;` is your best bet, with support from ie9+. Getting an `img` to cover the page without distorting only works if you know its size or are willing to use javascript.

Why do you need to use an `img`? Is it because you want the src to be added dynamically? in that case you should use an inline style.

```
<div style="background-image:{{dynamicImage}}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out yesterday before you posted, but this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** This solution is independent of the image dimensions, apart from that it needs its with to be greater than its height. It uses CSS positioning to set the image within `.full-screen` to be of full height, keep proportions and with a 50% negative horizontal offset (centered).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="full-screen">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.full-screen {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.full-screen img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5e6btwa2/1/

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't keep the image in proportion like the fiddle.

Comment: Oh, missed that part there.

Answer (score 0):

Try use attribute `align` with value `middle` in your `img` tag

```
 <img src="smth.gif" align="middle">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same behavior as you had with the image as a background, you could do it like this (depends on the [CSS3 transform method](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)):

http://jsfiddle.net/6y2qjxm0/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="full-screen">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background: inherit;
    /* overflow: hidden; enable to disable scrolling */
}
.full-screen {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.full-screen img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in IE8+ and pretty much every other browser:

### HTML

```
<div class="full-screen">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.full-screen {
      position: fixed; 
      top: -50%; /* this will center the image vertically */
      left: -50%; /* this will center the image horizontally*/
      width: 200%; 
      height: 200%;
}
.full-screen img {
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      margin: auto; 
      min-width: 50%;
      min-height: 50%;
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/6y2qjxm0/7/)

For other ways have a look at **[this article](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)** on CSS tricks by Chris Coyier. The CSS above is used in Technique #2 in his examples.